# Post data in asp vb.net webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap

I have created a web service in visual studio.  How do I read the HTTP post data when someone sends a request to one of my methods.

The message they are sending me is a soap wrapped xml file.

Comment: can we see what the signature of your web service looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method in the BeginRequest method in the Global.asax, here you can find the raw request.